# Has the Cause for the Canonization of Fr. Frederick W. Faber been Proposed?

Tags: catholicism, saint, canonization, sainthood, st-john-henry-newman

[*Fr. Frederick William Faber*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_William_Faber) became a member of the Oxford Movement under the leadership of St. John Henry Newman et al. in the 1830s. Many of its members, as a result of the condemnations levied upon the group by the Church of England at the time, lost their status at Oxford (e.g., William G. Ward) and/or became Catholics---such as Ward, Newman and Faber (the latter two, of whom, had also previously taken Anglican orders.)

Though Faber lived a relatively short life (49 years), he was a prolific writer and a zealous supporter of the Catholic Church. His writings, *e.g.*, [*The Precious Blood*](https://ia802701.us.archive.org/23/items/ThePreciousBlood/ThePreciousBlood_text.pdf) deal with topics most apropos to the confusion the Church is now suffering in the form of many clerics who promote ``gospels'' different from the *only one* preached by the Apostles.

QUESTION: Has the cause for Sainthood of Fr. Frederick William Faber ever been formally proposed by someone (a group) devoted to the effort?

Comment: Curiously, Faber was also the author of [this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Essay_on_Beatification_Canonization_a/lboLLTV9AXEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PP10&printsec=frontcover): Frederick William Faber, *An Essay on Beatification, Canonization, and the Processes of the Congregation of Rites.* London: Richardson and Son 1848, 140 pp.

Comment: @njuffa Many thanks for pointing this out and for providing the link.

Comment: @njuffa Also, it seems to me that a large part of what we know about the thoughts of St. Philip Neri is due largely to Fr. Faber who compiled a book of maxims and sayings of the Saint, who aside from some letters, did not seem to leave many writings behind. Wikipedia seems to have neglected to mention this book. Thanks again.

Comment: Might have to talk to the diocese in which he was associated with.

Comment: @KenGraham Thanks for the suggestion. It seems like a good place to start.